# Exporting the table from hive to Oracle server

Tags: oracle, hadoop, hive, hdfs, sqoop

When I am importing the table from Oracle db to hive is fine but when I am exporting the data from hive to db I got the error. I am performing the fallowing query operation.

```
sqoop export 
  --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@oragmp01prscan.enterprisenet.org:1521/GMP1PROD_RLB
  --username GMPAPMETA 
  --password welcome123 
  --table activity/
  --export-dir hdfs://user/hive/warehouse/activity/
```

ERROR:

```
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.run(ExportTool.java:100) 
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143) 
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70) 
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179) 
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218) 
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227) 
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236) 
15/11/05 01:18:28 ERROR tool.ExportTool: 
Encountered IOException running export job: 
java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter
```

Comment: ***WHAT*** error are you getting? Please post the complete and exact error message(s) here - after all, we cannot see your screen nor read your mind ....

Comment: error is 
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.run(ExportTool.java:100)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
15/11/05 01:18:28 ERROR tool.ExportTool: Encountered IOException running export job: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter

Comment: Please - **update** your original question with this information! It's really hard to read in a comment .....

Comment: there should be some more error info before the line with which you have started

Comment: when i am exporting the tables from hive to oracle i got this error

Comment: there is a slash(/) after your table name